# How to Have a Collapsible Container Respond to Transition property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wokring on trying to get a Clickabel Colapsible Container working mcuh like is seen on the [Obsidian Callouts Page](https://help.obsidian.md/Editing+and+formatting/Callouts). The Most interesting part of thislittle box that they have is that it ahs a smooth expanding transition.

Inspecting their HTML in the console reveals to me that the only change htey have is that they dynamicaly change the style on the `content` div

When Open `style=""`

When Closed `style="display:none"`

When Clicked from Close -> Open `style="overflow-y: clip; height: 98px; transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.47, 1) 0s;"`

When Clicked from Open -> Close`style="overflow-y: clip; height: 0px; transition: all 100ms cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.47, 1) 0s;"`

I then added extra text into hte content Div to see if it would break the transition property but it appears as if the height is put in dynamically and changes based on the content. With all this information i tried to put together my own little Callout verion using pure JS, CSS, HTML

```js
const Body = document.body
const FoldableContainer = document.createElement("div")
const FoldableHeader = document.createElement("div")
const FoldableContent = document.createElement("div")

FoldableHeader.innerHTML = "Clikc To Open"
FoldableHeader.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    FoldableContainer.classList.toggle("open")
    if(FoldableContainer.classList.contains("open")){
        FoldableContent.style.display = "inline"
        FoldableContent.style.height = "300px"
    }else{
        FoldableContent.style.display = "none"
        FoldableContent.style.height = "0px"
    }
    
})
FoldableContainer.className = "Container"
FoldableContainer.style.height = "auto"
FoldableContainer.style.padding = "50px"
FoldableContainer.style.width = "200px"
FoldableContainer.style.background = "#affaf7"
FoldableContainer.appendChild(FoldableHeader)

FoldableContent.innerHTML = "I am Text!. Infact im so much text that i make the Folable Container Div Larger!"
FoldableContent.style.backgroundColor = "#8fbdbb"
FoldableContent.style.transition = "all 1s"
FoldableContent.style.display = "none"
FoldableContent.style.height = "0px"
FoldableContainer.appendChild(FoldableContent)


Body.appendChild(FoldableContainer)
```

```css
html {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
div{
    user-select: none;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body></body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

As seen in the Snippet above with just changing the style i am unable to get a smooth transition and it is still a jaring OPEN or CLOSE.

Do i have a misunderstanding of how the transition property works?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is mostly correct, except that you cannot transition between `display:none` and another value. Think about what would "halfway between" that look like? How could that transition?

Instead you just need to transition the height and set `overflow:hidden` so that way when the div is small it will cut off the text.

See that below, and I greatly simplified your code as well

```js
var toggle = document.querySelector("#toggle");
var container = document.querySelector(".container");

toggle.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    container.classList.toggle("open")
});
```

```css
html {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container{
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #affaf7;
}

#foldable-content {
  background-color: #8fbdbb;
  transition: all 1s;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0px;
}

.open #foldable-content{
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id='toggle'>Click To Open</div>
  <div id="foldable-content">
    <div>I am Text!. In fact I am so much text that i make the Foldable Container Div Larger!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```